# Google Apis Map on my cordova jquery app doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm using cordova with jquery mobile. When I try to insert Maps of google Maps Apis, the maps doesn't appear. I have not understood the problem yet.
My code(api key removed):

```
    <div id="mappagps">Cavolo</div>
<script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mappagps"), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
</script>
<script src="js/my_geoloc.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key= *your_api_key* "></script>
```

And in the last raw of index.html I put:
    initMap()

Comment: set height to your div.  <div id="mappagps" style="height:100px; width: 70px">Cavolo</div>.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to set the callback for the google map script to call when he's finished: add `&callback=initMap` at the end of your google map script. (and also forgotten to give your div dimensions as said in Hasta Tamang's comment)

```html
<div id="mappagps" style="width: 100px; height: 100px">Cavolo</div>
<script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mappagps"), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
</script>
<!-- commented because we don't have this file: <script src="js/my_geoloc.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key= *your_api_key *&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: It doesn't work again. I cannot undrstand why. every plug in is installed

Comment: did you configure your app CORS to be able to communicate with google?

Comment: what I have to do?

Comment: you first should check if this is actually the problem, there should be a message showing in the console if the case (not in android console, it will show only in a brower console).

Comment: then if this a CORS issue, you have to add tag(s) to your config.xml, according to [the official documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html). Depending on your version, you should also add a `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="...">` tag to your index.html